# Mongo's bulkWrite with updateOne + upsert works the first time but gives duplicate key error subsequent times

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I'm using the Mongo-php-library to insert many documents into my collection (using bulkWrite). I want the documents to be updated if it already exists or to be inserted if it doesn't, so I'm using "upsert = true".

The code works fine the first time I run it (it inserts the documents), but the second time I run it it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\BulkWriteException: E11000 duplicate key error collection: accounts.posts index: postid dup key: { id: "2338...
```

I can't see anything wrong with my code. I have already gone through all SO posts but none helped.

This is my code:

```
// I prepare the array $post_operations with all updateOne operations
// where $data is an object that contains all the document elements I want to insert

    $posts_operations = array();
    foreach ($this->posts as $id => $data) {
        array_push($posts_operations, array('updateOne' => [['id' => $id], ['$set' => $data], ['upsert' => true]]));
    }

// Then I execute the method bulkWrite to run all the updateOne operations
    $insertPosts = $account_posts->bulkWrite($posts_operations);
```

It works the first time (when it inserts), but then it doesn't the second time (when it should update).

I have a unique index set up in the collection for 'id'.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: id already has a unique index, you don't need to make make your own. And the index that is violated is postid rather than id.

Comment: Thanks @D.SM, but I created an index for "id", not "_id". They are different.

Comment: "postid" is a unique index of the field "id" (not "_id")

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to fix it. I believe this might be a bug and I've reported it already in the Github repo.

The problem occurred only when "id" was a string of numbers. Once I converted "id" (the field that I was indexing) to an integer it works perfectly.